# How to copy files according to file list using batch script?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a folder with a multitude of files, and I have a list (txt) of specific files which I want to copy from this folder.

It will go something like this:
For each filename:
cp (filename in folder) to (filename in new_folder)

How can I do the above using batch script?

Comment: Does cd folder   copy *.txt newfolder  work?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to copy every *.txt file, but I have a txt file which contains a list of desired files I want to copy.

Comment: You have similar answer and question [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224880/batch-file-copy-files-with-certain-extensions-from-multiple-directories-into-one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate over the text file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (foo.txt) do
```

Copy the files:

```
copy "%%L" new_folder
```

Done:

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (foo.txt) do copy "%%L" new_folder
```

Comment: Which should be my current folder when running this?

Comment: So for your script I need to be in the folder with all of the files. I noticed that the batch doesn't work unless I have everything in one single line.

Comment: Worked great.  I put the single-line batch file and foo.txt in the same folder as the files to be copied.  I generated foo.txt with dir /b > foo.txt

Comment: @Tiberia, why would you bother with the text file in that case? Just use `for %%F in (*) do copy "%%F" new_folder` instead (or directly on the command line by replacing `%%F` with `%F`). However, in that case you can also use plain `copy`: `copy * new_folder`.

Comment: @Joey - Because I only wanted to copy certain files in that folder (which had hundreds of files.)  I generated a list of files, edited the list, and used this batch to copy them.